# how to reduce communication time in distributed teams

Tags: project-management, development-process, scrum, time-management, distributed-development

We have 10 distributed teams in our company and we are developing 3 huge web applications. A lot of time of our developers is spent with writing emails.

We are using scrum and for that we had a daily stand-up meeting, but other questions regarding product features, design issues are always communicated via email?

Is there a method or techniques available to reduce the time which is used to communicate!

Comment: a forum or wiki to which you can refer, this will also publish the issues for others to react to it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not about programming

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method or techniques available to reduce the time which is used to communicate!

Actually, our project have 3 distributed teams 2 located in oversea countries. The teams are using Agile scrum methodology. The method of communication that our company currently uses, might be called : **team lead communications** through video calls (**Lync** and **Skype**).

Because of the time differences, (9 and 7 hours) from US Eastern time, there is no way to have **daily stand-up** meeting for entire team (22 devs). However, it is managed by 3 team leads, through their communication in Skype.

Basically, each team works on their dedicated new development modules, bug fixes, data patches , etc. However, overall design, responsibilities and progress is daily discussed on high level between key developers.

**Note:** Above does **not** mean to **abandon email** communications, rather just to reduce them asap. As a solution, live video communications reduce the amount of emails and misunderstandings, and eliminates need to sent each specific problem to all Dev teams.

Comment: When it comes to discussing features / bugs screenshots are basically essential (for our web projects). You can have a look at [Usersnap](http://usersnap.com) - it's a tool which makes testing and bugreporting easier by attaching screenshots to bug tracker tickets.

Comment: @Gregor - yes you are right, we are also using Lync. It provides a lot of features, including the screen sharing.